# Need to know about advance ContentScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest, content-script

I need some help. I'm creating a Chrome extension that will just extract data from the webpage and shows on action popup.

I think it will be simple to interact with normal DOM. But currently, I'm working on [ticketmaster](https://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/) website, here is my GitHub repository link [click-master](https://github.com/devlopersabbir/click-master) (I have already added a preview video of what I have to do)

In the screenshot shown here, all elements is path, circle tag, and SVG, so firstly I have to listen user click the event that I already did.

[image: preview]

```
/** listen event */
    on("click", "#map-container", (event) => {
      console.log("event: ", event.target);
    });
```

I'm using (delegated-events) npm package to delegated event
. But it's not able to work with these element link when someone click 206 or any of box then it's not listen,
event I'm fully confused how can I read all event and to some task like when user click seat 1 then I have to auto click 2-3-4-5-6 I mean based on max ticket.

Can anyone help me to get some idea about this? How can I do this?

Comment: Try `mousedown` event instead of `click`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I passed this step :D